# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to build my project since I get this error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jabRh.png)

I tried every solution I could find but I had no luck. I'm using AS 2.1.3. This are my depencies:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

This morning I was able to work without problems, the only thing I did was some changes in an AsyncTask.

Comment: That happen mostly because of weak network or when the android studio is not able to download the library try to sync when network is good or you can download the lib. and sync also

Comment: My internet connection is good and I'm browsing the internet without issues right now.

Comment: mostly that type of error occur when android studio is not able to download the library you can add the library manually also just download the library . go to file->new->import module and add the location of your downloaded lib. then add the lib via project structure.

Comment: Mind telling me where to download it?

Comment: it worked or not ?? if not let me know

Comment: I solved it in another way. See my answer

Comment: I think when u deleted the gradel and restarted android studio created a new gradel by itself

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by deleting the .gradle folder in C:\Users\MyUsername.

Comment: Worked for Linux too.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in the network You just have to add

```
buildscript {
repositories {
  jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    // the latest version of the android-apt plugin
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
```

}

for apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' this library .Hope this will help [source](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/303)

Comment: I fixed it without touching my project files. See my answer.